# Assigning a number to a name without enumerating and printing a name based on that number

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is using n as the number of characters in list "Roles", print out the number n and the role next to it. Is there a way I can later, depending on the number I ask for, get a character that is "assigned"  to that number. I tried using enumerate, but I wasn't able to call the enumerated roles later with if/while/for or if I wanted to print them. I also tried using dictionary but you can't use append for dictionary. If it's possible to call the enumerated Roles, I would like to know how I can do that, if not I go back to my original question. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import random
Roles = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
SheriffList = []
Alive = []
for n in range(0, len(Roles)):
    random.shuffle(Roles)
    Role = random.choice(Roles)
    Alive.append(Roles.pop(Roles.index(Role)))
    Role2 = n,Role
    print(Role2)
    SheriffList.append(Role2)
    n += 1
    if n == len(Roles):
        random.shuffle(Alive)
        random.choice(Alive)

print(SheriffList)
   [(0, 'One'), (1, 'Four'), (2, 'Three'), (3, 'Two')]
k = int(input("Choose a number:"))
```

Now I want k (The number I choose), to be able to print me back the role that was assigned to it For example if I assign 1 to "k", it will send me 'Four'. I'm sorry if the question was already asked before, I just wasn't able to find what I needed.

Comment: if you want to work with *associations* between stuff, go with a `dictionary`.

Comment: What exactly is your goal in this `for` loop?

Comment: I used the for loop so I can first of all assign a number to every role, and second empty out the roles list and move the roles to the list alive

Answer (score 1):

A common way to solve this is to use an indirection table:

```
ind = [0, 3, 2, 1]
```

then to get the role corresponding at number `k`, you just use:

```
cur_role = Role[ind[k]]
```

Simple, clean and no need for loops...

Comment: Elegant indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do much, you could just keep a list. If you want `'One'` to be at index `1`, you could append a `None`:

```
>>> Roles = [None, "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
>>> Roles[2]
'Two'
>>> Roles[3]
'Three'
```

You could shuffle the list before appending `None`:

```
>>> roles = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
>>> random.shuffle(roles)
>>> roles
['Three', 'Four', 'Two', 'One']
>>> roles = [None] + roles
>>> roles[3]
'Two'
>>> roles[2]
'Four'
>>> roles[1]
'Three'
>>> roles[4]
'One'
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use a dictionnary:

```
import random
Roles = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
SheriffList = {}
Alive = []
for n in range(0, len(Roles)):
    random.shuffle(Roles)
    Role = random.choice(Roles)
    Alive.append(Roles.pop(Roles.index(Role)))
    #Role2 = (n, Role)
    SheriffList[str(n)]=Role
    #SheriffList.append(Role2)
    n += 1
    if n == len(Roles):
        random.shuffle(Alive)
        random.choice(Alive)

print(SheriffList)
 #  [(0, 'One'), (1, 'Four'), (2, 'Three'), (3, 'Two')]
k = int(input("Choose a number:"))
print(SheriffList[str(k)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will shuffle the Roles list and give you one of them based on a number from 0 to 3 given by the user.

```
import random

Roles = ['One','Two','Three','Four']

random.shuffle(Roles)

k = int(input('choose a number:'))

print(Roles[k])
```